# Can I black out a duplicated external display?

Tags: windows-10, external-display, intel-graphics

For presentations I *duplicate* my laptop screen to a projector. At times I want to black out the projector while keeping the laptop screen on. Preferably with a hotkey.

Powerpoint has this feature. (You press the B key.) But I'm using other software, so was hoping there would be a general solution.

Using Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics card.

What I tried:

- Just turning off the external display (projector) makes it go into standby mode, which is not a black screen but blue with text.
- Software called Multiscreen blank, but it also blacks out the laptop screen (because of duplicate/mirror mode)

I suppose this may not be possible, but asking just in case.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that would deduplicate a duplicate screen... Is there a specific reason you're not using the 'extended desktop' setting, and send the presentation to whichever of these is the public screen that you want to black out?

Comment: Hey. I don't extend the desktop because I would have to keep my back to the audience all the time to see what's on the screen. (The projector screen is right behind the teacher's desk.) I'm not using presentation software because the course material is on a website.

Comment: Powerpoint has a 'presenter mode' also exactly for this situation, you see what the audience sees + any slide notes you've kept. If you don't use slide notes, you can simply minimise that box. Which software are you using exactly?

Comment: Using mainly Firefox because the material is on a website. :) (But at times it may also be Adobe Reader or other programs.)

Comment: If you don't mind blacking out both screens, a quick fix would be to use your image viewer (for example irfanview) to show a pitch black jpg. I've used this in the past, although still in the extended desktop setup (so blacking out only one screen).

Comment: Thanks for helping out. That may be the way to go, though I was hoping to keep the laptop screen on. (I realize it's not a very common setup that I'm using...)

Comment: Give it some time, perhaps someone has an alternative solution. It will be something more exotic though, perhaps even something hardware based like a HDMI splitter with a button. No idea if anything like that exists though. I'll put the above in an answer just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that would deduplicate a duplicate screen. If the software you're using is not capable of a presentation mode and you're okay with a blackout button for both, you could try this:

- make a shortcut (on your desktop!) to a pitch black image
- add a keyboard shortcut in the shortcut properties:

[image]

I've used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> in this example.
If you're using Irfanview, you can configure it to close immediately when hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

[image]

Also disable 'show text' in the Full Screen settings tab (this removes the green filename and path text):

[image]

This should give you a quick blackout option regardless of which program runs.